# Startup animation from left to right in google line chart

Tags: javascript, charts, linechart

```
     google.charts.load('current', {
      packages: ['corechart', 'controls']
    }).then(function () {
      var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
        document.getElementById('dashboard')
      );

       var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
         'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
         'containerId': 'control',
         'options': {
           // Filter by the date axis.
           'filterColumnIndex': 0,
           'ui': {
             'chartType': 'LineChart',
             'chartOptions': {
               'chartArea': {'width': '84%'},
                 'hAxis': {'baselineColor': 'none', format: "dd.MM.yyyy" }
             }
           }
         },
       });

       var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
         'chartType': 'LineChart',
         'containerId': 'chart',
         'options': {
             animation:{
               startup:true,
            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'out'
          },
           tooltip: {isHtml: true},
           lineWidth: 4,
           legend: {position: 'none'},
           // Use the same chart area width as the control for axis alignment.
           'chartArea': {'height': '80%', 'width': '84%',interpolateNulls: true},
           hAxis: {
              title: ''
            },
            vAxis: {  format :<?php echo "'#.## ".html_entity_decode($currencyhtml[$userCurrency])."'"; ?>,
                        viewWindowMode:'pretty',
            gridlines: {
              count: 4,
            },
                       'slantedText': false,
              title: ''
            },
         }
         // Convert the first column from 'date' to 'string'.

       });



    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('date', 'Time of Day');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
            data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});


           var rawData = [

[new Date(2019,01,01), 1.00, 'example tooltip'],
[new Date(2019,01,03), 1.03, 'example tooltip'],
[new Date(2019,01,05), 2.00, 'example tooltip'],
[new Date(2019,01,07), 1.30, 'example tooltip'],
[new Date(2019,01,09), 1.00, 'example tooltip'],
[new Date(2019,01,11), 2.00, 'example tooltip'],
[new Date(2019,01,13), 1.10, 'example tooltip'],
[new Date(2019,01,15), 1.50, 'example tooltip'],
[new Date(2019,01,17), 1.20, 'example tooltip'],
[new Date(2019,01,19), 3.00, 'example tooltip'],
[new Date(2019,01,21), 1.30, 'example tooltip'],
[new Date(2019,01,23), 1.25, 'example tooltip']

            ];

      dashboard.bind(control, chart);

      drawChart();
      setInterval(drawChart, 1200);

      var rowIndex = 0;
      function drawChart() {
        if (rowIndex < rawData.length) {
          data.addRow(rawData[rowIndex++]);
          dashboard.draw(data);
        }
      }
    });
```

its working great so far but I would like to implement this startup animation ( [Google Visualization: Animated Line Graph --incremental rather than all at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39797001/google-visualization-animated-line-graph-incremental-rather-than-all-at-once) ) in my example. I tried to place

```
drawChart();
    setInterval(drawChart, 1200);

    var rowIndex = 0;
    function drawChart() {
      if (rowIndex < rawData.length) {
        data.addRow(rawData[rowIndex++]);
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    }
```

on the correct spot but the graph is not drawing at all :(. Anyone know what I have to do in my example to get this nice startup animation from left to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the data to a regular array,
then add one row at a time to the data table,
and draw the dashboard after adding each row.

see following snippet...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'controls']
}).then(function () {
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
    document.getElementById('dashboard')
  );

  var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'control',
    options: {
      // Filter by the date axis.
      filterColumnIndex: 0,
      ui: {
        chartType: 'LineChart',
        chartOptions: {
          chartArea: {
            width: '84%'
          },
          hAxis: {
            baselineColor: 'none',
            format: "dd.MM.yyyy"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    containerId: 'chart',
    options: {
      animation:{
        startup:true,
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'out'
      },
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true
      },
      lineWidth: 4,
      legend: {
        position: 'none'
      },
      // Use the same chart area width as the control for axis alignment.
      chartArea: {
        height: '80%',
        width: '84%',
        interpolateNulls: true
      },
      hAxis: {
        title: ''
      },
      vAxis: {
        format: <?php echo "'#.## ".html_entity_decode($currencyhtml[$userCurrency])."'"; ?>,
        viewWindowMode: 'pretty',
        gridlines: {
          count: 4,
        },
        slantedText: false,
        title: ''
      },
    }
  });

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Time of Day');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});

  rawData = [

    [new Date(".$date."), '".$value."'], ";
   ...
   ... (and so on) ...

  ];

  dashboard.bind(control, chart);

  drawChart();
  setInterval(drawChart, 1200);

  var rowIndex = 0;
  function drawChart() {
    if (rowIndex < rawData.length) {
      data.addRow(rawData[rowIndex++]);
      dashboard.draw(data);
    }
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

it appears the control's range was getting stuck on the first draw.
see following working snippet,
here, I set the axis range on the chart and control,
before each draw...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'controls']
}).then(function () {
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
    document.getElementById('dashboard')
  );

  var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'control',
    options: {
      filterColumnIndex: 0,
      ui: {
        chartType: 'LineChart',
        chartOptions: {
          animation:{
            startup:true,
            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'out'
          },
          chartArea: {
            width: '84%'
          },
          hAxis: {
            baselineColor: 'none',
            format: "dd.MM.yyyy"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    containerId: 'chart',
    options: {
      animation:{
        startup:true,
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'out'
      },
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true
      },
      lineWidth: 4,
      legend: {
        position: 'none'
      },
      chartArea: {
        height: '80%',
        width: '84%',
        interpolateNulls: true
      },
      hAxis: {
        title: ''
      },
      vAxis: {
        format: '#,##0',
        gridlines: {
          count: 4,
        },
        slantedText: false,
        title: ''
      },
    }
  });

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Time of Day');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2019,01,01), 1.00, 'example tooltip'],
    [new Date(2019,01,03), 1.03, 'example tooltip'],
    [new Date(2019,01,05), 2.00, 'example tooltip'],
    [new Date(2019,01,07), 1.30, 'example tooltip'],
    [new Date(2019,01,09), 1.00, 'example tooltip'],
    [new Date(2019,01,11), 2.00, 'example tooltip'],
    [new Date(2019,01,13), 1.10, 'example tooltip'],
    [new Date(2019,01,15), 1.50, 'example tooltip'],
    [new Date(2019,01,17), 1.20, 'example tooltip'],
    [new Date(2019,01,19), 3.00, 'example tooltip'],
    [new Date(2019,01,21), 1.30, 'example tooltip'],
    [new Date(2019,01,23), 1.25, 'example tooltip']
  ]);
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

  var dateRange = data.getColumnRange(0);
  chart.setOption('hAxis.viewWindow', dateRange);
  chart.setOption('vAxis.viewWindow', data.getColumnRange(1));

  dashboard.bind(control, chart);

  drawChart();
  setInterval(drawChart, 1200);

  var rowIndex = 0;
  var viewRows = [];
  function drawChart() {
    if (rowIndex < data.getNumberOfRows()) {
      viewRows.push(rowIndex++);
      view.setRows(viewRows);
      control.setState({range: {
        begin: dateRange.min,
        end: dateRange.max
      }});
      dashboard.draw(view);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard">
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <div id="control"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply! I changed the beginning and the end of the code and replaced rawData = [ ... ] but it is not working :(

Comment: please check the browser's console for errors (press F12) and edit the question with the latest code

Comment: code updated in the original post. got this error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Comment: do you maybe need the html as well?

Comment: probably not causing the error but need to change `var addRows` to `var rawData` -- or vice versa -- see `drawChart` function

Comment: the error is from the very last curly brace in the code you posted, change `}` to `});`

Comment: thank you very much for your help! Its working now, but its drawing the control panel under the chart instead of the chart itself. The chart stays fixed after the second rawdata and than only the control panel is changing. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: do you maybe have any solution for that?

Comment: if you could share a sample of the data, I could create a working example...

Comment: amazing! Thank you very much! Is it possible to prerender the graph so the graph axis are already scaled to the final values (that the graph has when drawing the last data row) when it starts to draw the graph?

Comment: another problem is that the control setting is not scaling the x axis correctly. It just let the lines disappear that are out of scoped but the x axis do not scale to full size like it is intended.

Comment: I tried it with viewWindow: {
          min: dateRange.min,
          max: dateRange.max
        } with an axis define but this seem not to work :( for the prerendering. At least it fixes the automatic scaling issue.